# Intercept click touch but not scroll in Android

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I've searching through web and doc to intercept a click event and let super manage scroll in an Android application.

Eg : by default when I scroll on my view an another view moved with it. I'm able to get click event but at the moment of I get onDown returning true; the other view is not able to scroll with it. I've tried to return false on onScroll by it didn't make it.

I've both code with basic onTouchListener or GestureDetectorCompat doing the same stuff.

WIth Gesture Detector :

```
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext, new ClickListener());

    mRootFrameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

class ClickListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDown");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onShowPress");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "click");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onScroll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLongPress");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFling");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to defer event on a special view with DispatchTouchEvent or anything else ?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm a bit surprised this hasn't been answered already. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Andy I don't know if it will answer your issue but here is what I remember. I achieve to listen for click and move event on a `ScrollView` with `wrap_content` where I needed to to let the scrollview scroll too. It's ptretty easy to do it in fact, as my view is inside it. Just listen for `onTouch` and register a `view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(listener);` You will get move event in this listener, scroll will still work and you will get click too.
see gist for `onTouch` method https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/d7fc6b654f6998e717de

Comment: There will be more problems when the ScrollView is inside SwipeRefreshLayout. Because we must intercept both at the same time(intercept swipe gesture and scroll gesture)